# How to denote a matrix of three indices?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology, definition

I have a "matrix" of three indices like $a_{kmn}$ for all $k=1,\ldots,K$, $m=1,\ldots,M$, and $n=1,\ldots,N$ (I think it is called a tensor of order 3, right?). I denote this "matrix" by the boldface letter $\mathbf{A}=[a_{kmn}]$. When I fix one "dimension" (say $k$), I write it as $\mathbf{A}_k$ which is now the $k$th matrix of size $M\times N$.

My question is: are my notations fine? Or are there any standard notations used?

Comment: Just to be aware: tensors are matrices, but they're matrices with additional properties, particularly with respect to coordinate transformations. The two terms are not completely equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notations are... notations. Just that. If they work for you and who reads you (if it were the case), they are ok.

Going to the question of standards, I guess the name "tensor" means more than just an array (a 3D array in this case): a tensor of rank three actually can have covariant and contra-variant dimensions and that has something to do with it's physical (or mathematical) meaning and transformation rules under a change of coordinates; this has indeed consequences for the notation ($T_k^{ij}$, $T_{jk}^{i}$, $T^{ijk}$, etc.). I would save the word "tensor" to use it restrictively, depending on the context, and I would rely on the term "array" (three dimensional array, in this case) for the general case.

You can say that $A$ has components $a_{ijk}$ and that $A\in \mathbb R^{m\times n \times p}$, for instance, but the notation $A_k$ for the matrix
$$B\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$$
with entries
$$b_{ij}=a_{ijk},$$
I find it ambiguous, since $A_k$ or $A_i$ would always mean that you're fixing the same index. This shortcoming becames evident when you use a number, say $A_3$: whith your notation this is the matrix of componentes $a_{ij3}$, $1\le i\le m$, $1\le j \le n$ and there's no way to refer to a matrix of components $a_{i3k}$ ($1\le i\le m$, $1\le k\le p$) or the analogous version for fixed $i=3$.

Maybe you can try instead of $A_k$, something like $A_{\cdot\cdot k}$, and so: in that case $A_{\cdot \cdot 3}$ and $A_{\cdot 3 \cdot}$, for instance, would not be in general the same matrix (actually they might well be of different sizes.

Even more, you can use $A_{i\cdot k}$ or $A_{ij\cdot}$ to get the one dimensional arrays (vectors) corresponding to fixing two indexes.

And this can actually be easily extended to $n$-dimensional arrays for arbitrary $n\in \mathbb N$.

NOTE: With this notation, you have $$A=A_{\cdot\cdot\cdot},$$ and of course usually you will just type $A$. Also, $$A_{ijk}=a_{ijk}$$ (or $$A_{ijk}=\big( a_{ijk}\big),$$ etc.), that is, a $1\times 1$ matrix, a $1$-dimensional vector or—much better— a $0$-dimensional array). That means that you need not make a difference between uppercase arrays and lowercase components (but it's not a crime either if useful).

---

FURTHER COMMENT on the 'inspiration' for this notation.

An situation where three or more indexes are needed arises in an experiment where measurements of a magnitude are taken for all combinations of the categories of classification of two (or more) properties (or factors, as they are called in experimental design). Supose that for every combination $(i,j)$ of the first and second factor (if we think of just two factors) there is more than one measurement and the number of repetitions is the same—say $K$—in each case: this is called a *balanced design*.

That is, we take the measurement $x_{ijk}$ which corresponds to the category $i$ for the first factor and $j$ for the second factor of classification, and it is the $k$-th repetition for that particular combination. For a balanced design of $K$ measurements for each combination of the $I$ categories in factor one and the $J$ categories in factor two, we get the $I\cdot J \cdot K$ measurements
$$x_{ijk}, \quad 1\le i\le I,\; 1\le j\le J,\; 1\le k\le K,$$
each is of which is seen as a realization of the random variable $X_{ijk}$.

A simple example: there 6 groups of 10 people, each corresponding to the six combinations of the *age* factor—with categories 'adolescent', 'adult' and 'elder'— and the *treatment* factor ('placebo' vs. 'actual medication'), and each one's arterial pressure is measured an hour after taking the (actual or pretended) medication. In this case you have $I=3$, $J=2$ (or viceversa) and $K=10$. And $x_{2,1,5}$ would be the arterial pressure as measured from the fifth individual in the group of adults who are having the placebo.

In the standard model with two factors for the *ANalysis Of VAriance* (*two-way ANOVA*) the statistical model is
$$X_{ijk}\sim N(\mu_{ij},\sigma^2),$$
all variables being independent. This can also be written
$$X_{ijk}=\mu_{ij}+\varepsilon_{ijk},\quad \varepsilon_{ijk}\sim N(0,\sigma^2),$$
and the $\varepsilon_{ijk}$ variables are independent.

In general, there are further details specifying the structure of the matrix $M=\big(\mu_{ij}\big)$, such as the *additive model*
$$\mu_{ij}=\mu+\alpha_i+\beta_j, \quad \sum_{i=1}^I \alpha_i=\sum_{j=1}^J \beta_j=0,$$
a model allowing for generic interactions such as
$$\mu_{ij}=\mu+\alpha_i+\beta_j+\gamma_{ij}, \quad \sum_{i=1}^I \alpha_i=\sum_{j=1}^J \beta_j=\sum_{i=1}^I \sum_{j=1}^J\gamma_{ij}=0,$$
which can be simplified to a *multiplicative model*
$$\mu_{ij}=\mu+\alpha_i+\beta_j+\lambda \alpha_i \beta_j, \quad \sum_{i=1}^I \alpha_i=\sum_{j=1}^J \beta_j=0,$$
etc.

So the data and the random variables $X_{ijk}$ form indeed a 3D-array, and when considering quantities such as sums ($S$), means ($\bar X$) or number of data ($n$), the convention of the dots (or sometimes another sign instead, such as $+$ for instance), is standard notation, as in:
$$n_{ij\cdot}\:\colon\: \text{number of data in the 'cell' or combination $(i,j)$ of factors}$$
(this is $K$ in a balanced design, but otherwise could vary among different $(i,j)$ combinations);
$$n_{i\cdot\cdot}\:\colon\: \text{number of data in the $i$-th category of the first factor of classification},$$
$$S_{ij\cdot}=\sum_{k=1}^K x_{ijk},$$
$$S_{\cdot j\cdot}=\sum_{i=1}^I\sum_{k=1}^K x_{ijk},$$
$$\bar x_{\cdot j\cdot}=\frac1{n_{\cdot j \cdot}}S_{\cdot j\cdot},$$
$$\bar x_{ij\cdot}=\frac1{n_{ij\cdot}}S_{ij\cdot},$$
$$\bar x_{\cdot \cdot \cdot}=\frac1{n_{\cdot\cdot\cdot}}S_{\cdot\cdot\cdot},$$
and so on (the last one is sometimes called the 'great mean').

I hope all the *blah* helps you get a taste of how this notation works.